# Httprequest doesn't work in batch although Database.AllowsCallouts implemented

Tags: apex, batch, httprequest

We are planning to start new integration functionality to a new system in our landscape (Workday). To do this we created integrations in apex with httpcallouts. We are planning to start the initial load via these same integrations but then with a batch.

However we are now running into an issue with this.

When we run the code to send 1 record via integration all goes fine.
When we run the code via a batch (with Database.AllowsCallouts implemented) we get an error on the line with:

```
HttpResponse response = http.send(httpRequest);
```

The error we get is:

```
14:55:06.0 (136688636)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[54]|System.UnexpectedException: Script-thrown exception
```

The strange thing is that it works outside of the batch and also on our sandbox environment (with the batch)
Is there any setting next to `Database.AllowsCallouts` to allow a call out in a batch class? or does anyone have

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! I don't think there's enough information right now to be able to point you towards any specific issue (or solution). Commenting out your callout and seeing what (if any) error you get might help. If you have a try/catch somewhere in there that's swallowing your exception, commenting it out may allow the underlying exception to surface (and hopefully give you a better indication as to what's going wrong). You can [edit] your question to add more details.

Comment: Also, when trying to resolve problems with code, it is much harder to provide help if you don't share the relevant parts of the code with us (doesn't necessarily need to be the entire class, just enough to see what is failing and enough context to understand where all of the relevant variables and such are coming from).

Comment: `System.UnexpectedException` often means something edge-casey has happened. Are you combining any features with this callout in the same transaction that might be ... unusual? Big Objects, Platform Events, something else?

Answer (score 0):

After debugging I found the issue that the named credential was written incorrect. A capital in the middle made a big difference. Thanks for the responses!